# Strange messages in console

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal, cmake

This just started happening to me now when I turned on my computer.  I have no idea what caused it, and Google searches seem to show that this was fixed a year ago in various message boards but does not explain how to fix it.  When I open a terminal, I get the following messages:

```
bash: debian/tmp/usr/share/cmake-3.0/completions/cmake: No such file or directory
bash: debian/tmp/usr/share/cmake-3.0/completions/cpack: No such file or directory
bash: debian/tmp/usr/share/cmake-3.0/completions/ctest: No such file or directory
```

Doing a man or a which on these 3 utilities (cmake, cpack, ctest) shows nothing wrong with them, so I don't think my computer is broken.  I just want to know why these messages are appearing and how to make them go away.  Thanks.

Comment: Does it happen each time you open  a new terminal ?

Comment: Whats the output of `grep -nE 'cmake|cpack|ctest' ~/.bashrc /etc/bash.bashrc ~/.profile /etc/profile`

Comment: Actually I was able to fix it myself.  It started when I added a new ppa to my software sources and overwrote the default version of cmake.  I removed the ppa and reinstalled the default version of cmake and the problem went away.  For further information, this is what I did to cause the issue:

https://github.com/Cockatrice/Cockatrice/wiki/Compiling-Cockatrice#ubuntu-14xx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was able to fix it myself.  It started when I added a new ppa to my software sources and overwrote the default version of cmake.  I removed the ppa and reinstalled the default version of cmake and the problem went away.  For further information, this is what I did to cause the issue, and I simply undid it to fix it:

https://github.com/Cockatrice/Cockatrice/wiki/Compiling-Cockatrice#ubuntu-14xx

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this same problem, and I think it's caused by the same thing--trying to compile cockatrice. Could you describe in more detail how you removed the ppa and reinstalled default cmake? I can't seem to remove the ppa.